# Problem with compability High DPI scaling override after upgrading to NET 7

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-7.0

We have a NET Framework 4.8 Winforms application which was upgraded to NET 7.
On NET Framework 4.8, in high dpi configurations the application appeared blurry and the window size was wrong but by just setting the `High DPI scaling override` to `Application` in compatibility (in the executable properties) fixed it, with everything looking like it should.
After upgrading to NET 7 (forms weren't changed) doing the same process to fix the application scaling, leads to enlarged forms and controls sometimes going over each other.

I was expecting the same scaling behaviour as when the application was on .NET Framework 4.8, i looked on internet how to fix scaling issues on high dpi but it just points to rewriting the forms partially to accommodate for it or setting the compatibility options programmatically (which still doesn't have the wanted behaviour). On NET Framework 4.8,the program already had the wanted behaviour (with dpi override at least) so there should be some way to recreate it on NET 7 without having to rewrite the forms. Is there a way to recreate the scaling behaviour i had with .NET framework 4.8 on .NET 7? Does seem like some NET Core/.NET version changed how the application did scaling

[image: DPI SCALING]

EDIT: Specified im using Winforms, somehow i forgot to say that

Comment: Winforms, thanks for asking, somehow i forgot to mention the most important part

Comment: A .NET 7 application is DpiAware by default (`SystemAware`, for now). .NET Framework app is not. You usually set the DpiAwareness you have planned to design your app for. If you haven't, for some reason, - you're probably letting the app scale to Font (as the *ancient default*) -- In a .NET 7 app, you may want to try first how it looks like when you set `<ApplicationHighDpiMode>PerMonitorV2</ApplicationHighDpiMode>` in your Project file. If you're not happy with it, then try `DpiUnawareGdiScaled`, then `DpiUnaware` -- If you're still not happy, you most probably have to redesign the UI

Comment: A suggestion: if you have used another *ancient default*, `Microsoft Sans Serif` as Font, you should really change that Font. `Segoe UI` is the intended replacement, now the default in .NET. `Microsoft YaHei UI` is another good choice